# Writing IF statement for ODD numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to write an IF statement such as this

```
 IF (value in column A is ODD, then do this)
 IF (value in column A is EVEN, then do this)
```

With the cells having both letters and numbers in them (i.e. cells would have the following format in a column: A1, A2, A3, etc.). This is my current formula:

```
=IF(EVEN(A13)=A13, I13, L13),
```

However, I can't somehow manipulate it such that it omits the letter in the cell and just looks at the number. Any suggestions would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Will it always be one letter? Just substitue `A13` with `RIGHT(A13, LEN(A13)-1)`

Comment: Not always, a cell could look like (AB24 or ABC24). I just want to look at the numerical value and write a formula incorporating this into an IF statement looking to see whether the numerical value is even or odd.

Comment: So the number is always at the very end of the string?

Comment: The VBA function `IIF()` (inline if) works much the same way as Excel's `IF` formula.

Comment: The letters and numbers are in mixup (AB12F8) or always letters at the start, numbers at the end?

Comment: Mostly the numbers are at the end i.e. AF13, ABF 14, etc. but they can occasionally mix up as in Blenikos' example. Is there a general formula that cover both these scenarios or possibly two sets of general formulas for each scenario?

Comment: @tellap If they can occasionally mix up as in `AB12F8` then what is the expected output for that scenario? `12 = even` and `8 = even` or `128 = even`? All other scenarios with numbers at the end only (including spaces - not between each number) are handled by my formulas below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an array formula that will work but I think there is a simpler way. You'll need to press `ctrl`+`shft`+`enter`:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(VALUE(MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),"")),
LEN(A1)-MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),""))+1))),I1,L1)
```

Here is the non-array version. Just press `enter`:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(VALUE(MID(A1,MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A1&
{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})),LEN(A1)-MIN(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},
A1&{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}))+1))),I1,L1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To test for evenness of a number, it is sufficient to perform the test on the last digit only of that number.

As such, and if the numbers only appear at the end of the string, then:

`=ISEVEN(RIGHT(A1))`

Regards

Comment: I don't think he needs to check evenness. He wants to use the even function that rounds the number to the nearest even number.

Comment: Are you sure? The initial statement says " IF (value in column A is EVEN, then do this)...". And look again at how the OP's formula is actually using the EVEN function here.

Comment: To be honest, the thing that bugs me with that question is exactly that: EVEN(A13)=A13. It doesn't make any sence. A13 is a cell? A string? You are right on your assumptions.However on the comments on the questions he asks a different thing. I suppose we will never know! I don't think the OP is a regular SO user

Comment: Actually a construction such as EVEN(A13)=A13 makes perfect sense, assuming of course that you have never come across the function ISEVEN, since, for testing for evenness, that construction is identical to ISEVEN(A13) for all cases where the value in A13 is an integer.

Comment: You are right!!!!!! I haven't seen that until now!!! Propably that is what he wants (except in case letters and numbers are really mixed/messed up). +1 from me

Comment: Thanks! Yes, if the numbers are not all at the end then the OP will need to respond to Brian's comment to clarify the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vba function that I use to extract numbers from a string:

```
Public Function numer(val As Variant) As Double
Dim collector As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Len(val)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(val, i, 1)) Or Mid(val, i, 1) = "," Then: _
    collector = collector + Mid(val, i, 1)
Next i

numer = CDbl(collector)
```

End Function

You can add that on a new module and then use it inside your formulas as you wish (like a normal excel function, see below in the screenshot).

[image: Result]

For more info on how to do this (use a vba function in your formulas) please take a look here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

If you need to have a coma for decimal places inside your number, you have to change a little bit the if statement in that function to accept commas.

**EDIT:** I've improved the function to accept decimal numbers (with comma) and also I have created a more complex exampel for you that shows how to use the function with the result (In column B on my screenshot) and how to use it inside a formula with IF.